# Технология соц.сети

Tags: php, сеть, mysql

Правильно ли я думаю,о работе соц.сети.

Когда пользователь уже зарегистрирован, и он проходит авторизацию.

Если авторизация прошла успешно, его логин сохраняется в сессии, и передается на все следующие страницы.

И этот логин используется для обращения к БД???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Насколько я понял вопрос - да, именно так. Пользователь авторизовывается, вы записываете, например, его логин (можно еще что-то, не суть) в сессию. Суть в том что авторизация подтверждает права того или иного пользователя ну и, с точки зрения кода, открывает сессию того или иного пользователя.

Ну и потом, конечно-же, вы можете использовать данные записанные в сессию в своих запросах к БД.